# Clickable text scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this website - "https://www.realcommercial.com.au/sold/?autoSuggest=false&page=1/". I have successfully **scraped** all the required data, except the phone numbers which are clickable text. below is my code

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = []
for i in range(1,4):
    pages = "https://www.realcommercial.com.au/sold/?autoSuggest=false&page={0}".format(i)
    urls.append(pages)

Data = []
for info in urls:
    page = requests.get(info)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('a', attrs ={'class' :'Address_link_1aaSW'})
    hrefs = [x['href'] for x in links]
    s = "https://www.realcommercial.com.au"
    href = [s + x for x in hrefs ]
    for m in href:
        entry=[]
        pages = requests.get(m)
        soup_2 =BeautifulSoup(pages.content, 'html.parser')
        Add_st = soup_2.find_all('h1', attrs={'class' :'Address_container_3HZgj'})
        Address_Street = [Address_Street.text.strip() for Address_Street in Add_st]
        Prop = soup_2.find_all('div', attrs={'class' :'PrimaryDetails_propertyTypes_1SLzV'})
        Prop_Type = [Prop_Type.text.strip() for Prop_Type in Prop]
        Dtnarea = soup_2.find_all('div', attrs ={'class' :'Attribute_attribute_3lq_3'})
        Date = [Date.text.strip() for Date in Dtnarea]
        Land_Area = [x for x in Date if x.startswith('Land Area')]
        Floor_Area = [y for y in Date if y.startswith('Floor Area')]
        Sold_date =  [z for z in Date if z.startswith('Sold on')]
        Agency = soup_2.find_all('a', attrs={'class' :'AgencyPanel_agencyNameLink_nCd-h'})
        Agency_Name = [Agency_Name.text.strip() for Agency_Name in Agency]
        Agent = soup_2.find_all('h4', attrs={'class' :'AgentDetails_name_23QWU'})
        Agent_Name = [Agent_Name.text.strip() for Agent_Name in Agent]
        
        phone = [broth['href'] for broth in soup_2.select("#wrapper > div > div.DetailContainer_detailPage_2O71T > div:nth-child(7) > div.AgencyPanel_wrapper_mVRp2 > div > ul > li > div.AgentDetails_details_28P5A > div.AgentDetails_actions_2CKN0 > a")]
        Phone_Number = [Phone_Number.text.strip() for Phone_Number in Phone]
```

For phone number, i am getting the below output :-

```
0        [#, #, #]
1           [#, #]
2           [#, #]
3              [#]
4              [#]
5           [#, #]
6           [#, #]
7           [#, #]
8           [#, #]
9           [#, #]
10          [#, #]
11          [#, #]
12          [#, #]
13          [#, #]
14          [#, #]
15          [#, #]
16    [#, #, #, #]
17          [#, #]
18          [#, #]
```

How can i click on the text & get the hidden phone numbers.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code.

You can click phone link first to display phone number with selenium.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

urls = []
for i in range(1,4):
    pages = "https://www.realcommercial.com.au/sold/?autoSuggest=false&page={0}".format(i)
    urls.append(pages)

Data = []

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# hidden browser
options.add_argument('headless')  
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

for info in urls:
    page = requests.get(info)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('a', attrs ={'class' :'Address_link_1aaSW'})
    hrefs = [x['href'] for x in links]
    s = "https://www.realcommercial.com.au"
    href = [s + x for x in hrefs ]
    print(href)
    for m in href:
        browser.get(m)
        entry=[]
        pages = requests.get(m)
        soup_2 =BeautifulSoup(pages.content, 'html.parser')

        # Find all phone number link elements
        phone_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#wrapper > div > div.DetailContainer_detailPage_2O71T > div:nth-child(7) > div.AgencyPanel_wrapper_mVRp2 > div > ul > li > div.AgentDetails_details_28P5A > div.AgentDetails_actions_2CKN0 > a')
        # Using JavaScript to click it -> execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link)
        # You can also use selenium click() method -> "link.click()" if you want to simulate user behavior 
        # I prefer to use JS because it performs clicking better.
        for link in phone_links:
            browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link)
        # Retrieve phone number text elements from <span>
        phones = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#wrapper > div > div.DetailContainer_detailPage_2O71T > div:nth-child(7) > div.AgencyPanel_wrapper_mVRp2 > div > ul > li > div.AgentDetails_details_28P5A > div.AgentDetails_actions_2CKN0 > a > span')
        # Get the phone number text
        for phone in phones:
            print(phone.text)
```

And this is output:

```
0433 047 000
0419 355 561
0413 860 304
0413 860 315
0417 516 531
+61 408 892 976
+61 439 400 081
0419 355 561
0410 545 226
0427 632 030
0448 486 665
0418 772 555
0407 964 013
0418 771 340
0498 121 165
0418 888 840
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response, however, i am receiving the below error while trying to run this,
       WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: Isn't it possible to accomplish this using beautifulsoup ?

Comment: browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="your chromedriver path")

Comment: I can't find out solution without Selenium yet.

Comment: I am still getting the below error

     WebDriverException: Message: Service C:/Program Files 
     (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status 
     code was: 0

Comment: You should download chromedriver. And the path is chromedriver not chrome.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It worked for me, Can you please explain how does the piece of code(for phone number) works, as i am not well versed with selenium & drivers

Comment: @renu Hi, I add explanation in code. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Hi, Awesome !! Thank you so much for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

Phone numbers come from API calls that use listing ids as a parameter. The following you can play around with. Property info is actually within script tag for each page so I extract those listings and the ids and store in a dictionary using the id as key. I then issue the API request using the id param and extract from response a tel number, agency, and a single agent name. There is lots more info (everything you need available in this process)

```
import requests,re,json

api_base = 'https://api.realcommercial.com.au/listing-ui/listings/'
p = re.compile(r'pageData = (.*?);', re.DOTALL)
results = {}
ids = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    for page in range(4):
        r = s.get(f'https://www.realcommercial.com.au/sold/?autoSuggest=false&page={page}')
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')   
        data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])

        for item in data['exactMatchListings']:
            item_id = item['id']
            if item_id not in ids:
                ids+=item_id
                results[item['id']] = item
                item_json = s.get(f'{api_base}{item_id}').json()['listing']['agencies'][0]
                agency = item_json['name']
                try:
                    named_agent = item_json['salespeople'][0]['name']
                except:
                    named_agent = 'N/A'
                tel = item_json['phone']['dial']
                print(item_id, agency,  named_agent, tel)
```